# How do I add a JavaScript event handler so that when the user moves the mouse cursor onto the content element a timeout timer starts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what I am trying to do,
I want to add a JavaScript event handler so that when the user moves the mouse cursor onto the content element, a timeout timer is started that will set the opacity of the payWall element to 1.0 – three second later.

Then I want to dd another JavaScript event handler so that when the user clicks the subscribe button, an alert box appears with the message “Subscribing now.” 
When the alert is OK-ed, the payWall slides down the page and out of sight. I think I will need to set an interval timer so that the payWall moves down like 2 pixels every 30 milliseconds.

I am not sure how to do it, I tried my best, but if someone can please help me, I would really appreciate it.

```js
function init()
{
 
    document.getElementById("subscribe").onclick = function()
 {

 }   
}

window.onload=init;
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
h2, h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    height: 100px;
}
#footer {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
#header, #footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#leftnav, #rightnav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

#rightnav{ 
    left: 80%;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#content div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
    
#content div:hover {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: white;
}
    
#content {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 20%;
 border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------*/
#payWall {

    background-color : darkseagreen;
    font-size: 2em;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    The Header
</div>

<div id="wrapper"> <!-- Can be used to apply bg colour -->

<div id="leftnav">
    <h4> Left</h4>
</div>
<div id="rightnav">
    <h4> Right</h4>
</div> 
    
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <h2> Article 1 </h2>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 2 </h2>
        <p>
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2> Article 3 </h2>
        <p>
            Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis nibh hendrerit.
            Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar.
            Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem.
            Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis.
            Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet.
            Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac.
        </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
    
</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
    
<div id="footer">
<h3>
    The End
</h3>
<div id="payWall">
    For further access please subscribe here. <br>
    <button id="subscribe"> Subscribe</button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

[image: Example!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
Use `<div onmouseenter='setTimeout(doStuff, 3000)'>` for a three second delay when the cursor enters the div

In JS:
Add a function, `doStuff`, which has the following code:

```
document.getElementById('payWall').style.opacity = '1';
document.getElementById('subscribe').onclick = function(){
    alert("Subscribing now");
    vanishPayWall();
}
```

One problem is that the `payWall` would just keep moving down the page. If you wanted it to disappear, you'd want to put `overflow-y: hidden` on the payWall, and shorten the paywall by 2px every time as well as setting the upper margin to 2px higher. Maybe something like

```
function vanishPayWall() {
    var key = window.setInterval(function(){
        var pw = document.getElementById('payWall');
        pw.style.height = String(Number(pw.style.height.slice(-2)) - 2) + 'px';
        pw.style.marginTop = String(Number(pw.style.height.slice(-2)) + 2) + 'px';
    }, 25)
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(key)
    }, Number(pw.style.height.slice(-2)) * 12.5)
}
```

Not absolutely sure this will work, but it should help out a bit.